# Create a static libary and link against it

Tags: c, gcc, static

Hello beautiful people,

i'm trying to create a static libary and to compile against it.
I've allready created a small static libary and a header for it.

Header (math.h):

```
int add (int a, int b);
int sub (int a, int b);
```

add.c:

```
int add (int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

sub.c:

```
int sub (int a, int b) { return a - b; }
```

I've created my static libary with the following commands:

```
gcc -c add.c

gcc -c sub.c

ar rcs libmymath.a add.o sub.o
```

Now my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    printf("Result : %d\n", add(5,7) );
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile it with the following command:

```
gcc main.c libmymath.a -o main
```

But if i compile it the following way, it fails.

```
gcc main.c -lmymath -L. -o main
```

It fails with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmymath collect2:

error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

even a change to

```
gcc main.c -llibmymath -L. -o main
```

fails and even if i include the header mymath.h to gcc
Can you help me ?

Comment: Order of arguments matter. Put the library search path argument `-L.` before the linker-library option `-lmymath`.

Answer (score 1):

gcc understood -lmymath by libmath.so or libmath.a already. So when you add lib word in -llibmymath. This case the gcc understood your library name being liblibmymath.a. So, please replace this command

```
gcc main.c -llibmymath -L. -o main
```

by

```
gcc main.c  -o main -L. -lmymath
```

It should work.